# What does the Qt.Popup window flag entail?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt5

I'm using PyQT5 to create a GUI. Basically, what I want is a transparent window that extends the **entire** width and height of the screen (including the toolbar and dock on MacOS)

The code I am using to achieve this is like so:

```
class Gui(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):

    #Initialize the QApp/QWidget things
        super().__init__()

    #Add a default rectangle
        self.rectangle = QRect(0, 0, 0, 0)

    #Build the window in a method to keep the init clean
        self.buildWindow()

    #Build the window
        def buildWindow(self):

    #Make the window transparent
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.Popup)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
    #Maximize the window
        self.resize(1920, 1080)
    #Enable mouse tracking
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
    #Render the window
        self.show()
```

I open the GUI like so:

```
#Instantiate our app and Gui stuff.
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = Gui()
#Make the cursor the "cross cursor" for effect
    app.setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt.CrossCursor))
#Exit when our app exits
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The issue is that the GUI opens, renders for a second, and disappears immediately. If I remove `Qt.Popup` from the window flags, it will do exactly what I want it to do (but it will not extend past the dock or the toolbar on MacOS)

I've heard that this problem is causes (*generally*) by a widget being rendered and leaving the scope due to Python's garbage collection system, but I'm unsure if that is the problem here because it will *actually render* if I remove the `Qt.Popup`

Anyone who has experience with QT and could help would be awesome.. I've been trying to figure out this bug for a couple days.

EDIT: If you can't tell already, I am developing this on MacOS

Comment: Can you not just use [`QWidget.showFullScreen()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qwidget.html#showFullScreen)?

Comment: `QWidget.showFullScreen()` will not work as it creates a space separate from the desktop. I need this to extend over the current desktop (dock and toolbar)

Comment: Firstly, `Qt.Popup` is typically used for menus. It should not be used for windows. Secondly, Its the window manager's job to decide the area available to your window. You cannot override it from Qt user space. You'll have to get your hands dirty and see how to tweak your window manager.